# Codeigniter 3 autoload controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, autoload, codeigniter-restserver

I'm using [REST Server](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) in codeigniter, and the way to use is that then in my app in all my controllers I must write this line on start:

```
require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
```

Does anyone know how to autoload this REST_Controller and to avoid this line in all my controllers? I don't want to use require.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this through `Codeigniter`'s autoload configuration.

Edit your project's `autoload.php` which is located in directory `YourProject/application/config/`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('REST_Controller');
```

And in controllers access this library class through `$this->rest_controller`.

BTW: Rest_Controllers is a library file, so I don't think a name suffixed with `Controller` is a good name for it.

***Edit***

Through your comment I got that you actually mean all of your controllers extended from `REST_Controller`, and you don't want require it at the top of every controller file.

Solution:

1. Move `REST_Controller.php` into directory `YourProject/application/core/`.
2. In `YourProject/application/config/config.php` line 119 change `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';` to `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'REST_';`

then `Codeigniter` will load `REST_Controller` automatically.

But the `subclass_prefix` config has a global effect, and you need change the location of `REST_Conttoller.php`, so to make minimal change I think the best way is you create `MY_Controller` class in directory `./application/core/` and require `REST_Controller` at bottom of this new file. When `CI` load `MY_controller` automatically `REST_Controller` will be required too.

***Notice:*** `MY_Controller` need extending from `CI_Controller`

Comment: All my controllers extend REST_Controller. So If I put in autoload in packages REST_Controller, I can't use $this->rest_controller, because I have to use before class started : class Users extends REST_Controller {}

Comment: Ok, I know, I will edit my answer and provide solution for this.@Sasa

Comment: I move REST_Controller in core folder and changed subclass_prefix, and working. With another solution I couldn't make app working, so I will keep first solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Sasa may be you forgot to change subclass_prefix's value to `'MY_'` when you use second solution. Anyway, good to hear this answer works for you :)

Comment: No I haven't, I wrote MY_ for subclass_prefix and got that error

Answer (score 3):

Put file include in constructor of `MY_Controller` class, then extend it to any controller that needs to use `REST_Controller`. 
If you don't have `MY_Controller.php` file in `APPPATH.'core/'` location, make one and use it as presented here:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('See you next time.');

//APPPATH.'core/' location
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        require APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php';//this constant ends with slash already
    }
}
```

Now, in every controller you want to use REST_Controller have code like this:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('See you next time.');

//example controller
class Api extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //bare example method
    public function some_get()
    {
        echo '<pre>', var_dump('Some REST_Controller code logic here'), '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't manage with this solution, got error 404 not found.

Comment: I wrote that it is an example controller with example method. Update your question with how did you use it exactly so I could help more.